# How do i get the dataset attribute of this element?

Tags: javascript

I want to console.log multiply, what am I doing wrong?

```
       <button class="key--operator" data-action="multiply">&times;
        var doms = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
        const data = doms.dataset.action;
        console.log(data);
```

Comment: Hi there, have you seen the [Mozilla Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) about dataset before going here?

Answer (score 0):

doms is has array of buttons it needs an index.

```
var doms = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
const data = doms.dataset.action;
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Hi there, you may wanna go and tell us more about what you are doing here, and provide some documentation with your explaination too.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it this way:

```
var doms = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
console.log(doms[0].getAttribute('data-action'));
```

Comment: This is not the standard way to fetch Data attributes. Read the documentation on [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) before answering.

Comment: Where did you find in the documentation that it is the "standard" way?
Data attribute is the DOM element attribute as well. So both ways works.
Moreover check the browser support for datasets and getAttribute ;)